# Управление параллельными потоками

Tags: python, многопоточность

Добрый день ! Не могу разобраться в модуле threading . Весь день голову ломаю . 
Запускаются 4 параллельных потока . Время работы каждого потока от 0.2 до 1 секунды . Потоки запускаются в бесконечном цикле . Важно , чтобы каждый поток ожидал завершения самого последнего потока и только потом начинал новый цикл.

```
import threading
import time

def write(x,delay):
    while True:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print("Process # {} is finished ...".format(x))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=[1,0.2])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=write1, args=[2,0.4])
t4 = threading.Thread(target=write1, args=[3,0.6])
t3 = threading.Thread(target=write1, args=[4,1])

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Для такой задачи идеально подойдёт [барьер](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects):

```
import threading
import time

b = threading.Barrier(4, timeout=5)

def write(x, delay):
    while True:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print("Process # {} is finished ...".format(x))
        b.wait()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=[1, 0.2])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=[2, 0.4])
t4 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=[3, 0.6])
t3 = threading.Thread(target=write, args=[4, 1.0])

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
```